# Sockets with Python

Tags: python-2.7

I have just started learning python. I just got to the chapter of sockets and came across the following code:

```
import socket
import sys


HOST = ''
PORT = 4444

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print "Our socket is created"

try:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error as e:
    print "Error in binding the port"
    sys.exit()
print "Binding is complete"

s.listen(20)
print "Server is in listen mode now!"

while 1:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print "Connected with the : " + addr [0] + ' : ' +str(addr[1])
    s.close()
```

When i run the code it works fine, but when i try to connect to the port on 4444 i get the following error in the console which i can't figure out why:

I am trying to connect to localhost on port 4444 using putty, i tried ssh, telnet and raw and all of them yield the same error

```
Our socket is created
Binding is complete
Server is in listen mode now!
Connected with the : 127.0.0.1 : 49278
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\pythontraining\Module12\server-working.py", line 24, in <module>
    conn, addr = s.accept()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 206, in accept
    sock, addr = self._sock.accept()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 174, in _dummy
    raise error(EBADF, 'Bad file descriptor')
socket.error: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Comment: anyone have any idea why i would be getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

I think the error occurred from the socket that has not been available even the connection thread is alive.

Try fix indention on

> s.close()

```
.
.
while 1:
  conn, addr = s.accept()
  print "Connected with the : " + addr [0] + ' : ' +str(addr[1])

s.close()
```